# cryptsetup, grub-probe errors when autoremoving kernels using apt

Tags: apt, kernel, cryptsetup

My server is located in Hetzner and is using their Ubuntu 14.04 deployed image with no encryption of partitions to my knowledge. Machine uses 2 plate drives and are configure in software RAID. The errors have been showing up for quite some time now. I am not educated enough to pinpoint the root of this evil behavior of my Ubuntu 14.04.5. When I run `apt-get autoremove`, the console outputs this:

```
apt-get autoremove 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libclamav6 linux-headers-3.19.0-65 linux-headers-3.19.0-65-generic
  linux-headers-3.19.0-66 linux-headers-3.19.0-66-generic
  linux-headers-3.19.0-68 linux-headers-3.19.0-68-generic
  linux-headers-3.19.0-69 linux-headers-3.19.0-69-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-91-generic linux-image-3.13.0-92-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic linux-image-3.13.0-95-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-96-generic linux-image-3.19.0-65-generic
  linux-image-3.19.0-66-generic linux-image-3.19.0-68-generic
  linux-image-3.19.0-69-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-91-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-92-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-95-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-96-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-65-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-66-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-68-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-69-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 27 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
27 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 2,141 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 442749 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-91-generic (3.13.0-91.138) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-91-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-91-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-91-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-91-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-91-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/md/2
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-91-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-91-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
grub-probe: error: disk `mduuid/00db37a2ad5b8d86c2b04f8cadb67df3' not found.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-91-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.13.0-91-generic (3.13.0-91.138) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-91-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-91-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-91-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-91-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-91-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
grub-probe: error: disk `mduuid/00db37a2ad5b8d86c2b04f8cadb67df3' not found.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-91-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-91-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-92-generic (3.13.0-92.139) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-92-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-92-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-92-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-92-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-92-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/md/2
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-92-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-92-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
grub-probe: error: disk `mduuid/00db37a2ad5b8d86c2b04f8cadb67df3' not found.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-92-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.13.0-92-generic (3.13.0-92.139) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-92-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-92-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-92-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-92-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-92-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
grub-probe: error: disk `mduuid/00db37a2ad5b8d86c2b04f8cadb67df3' not found.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-92-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-92-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic (3.13.0-93.140) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-93-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-93-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-93-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-93-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-93-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/md/2
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-93-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-93-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
grub-probe: error: disk `mduuid/00db37a2ad5b8d86c2b04f8cadb67df3' not found.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic (3.13.0-93.140) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-93-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-93-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-93-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-93-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-93-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
grub-probe: error: disk `mduuid/00db37a2ad5b8d86c2b04f8cadb67df3' not found.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-95-generic (3.13.0-95.142) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-95-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-95-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-95-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-95-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-95-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/md/2
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-95-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-95-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
grub-probe: error: disk `mduuid/00db37a2ad5b8d86c2b04f8cadb67df3' not found.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-95-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-image-3.13.0-95-generic (3.13.0-95.142) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-95-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-95-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-95-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-95-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-95-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
grub-probe: error: disk `mduuid/00db37a2ad5b8d86c2b04f8cadb67df3' not found.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-95-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-95-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-96-generic (3.13.0-96.143) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-96-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-96-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-96-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-96-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-96-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/md/2
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-96-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-96-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
grub-probe: error: disk `mduuid/00db37a2ad5b8d86c2b04f8cadb67df3' not found.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-96-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-image-3.13.0-96-generic (3.13.0-96.143) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-96-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-96-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-96-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-96-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-96-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
grub-probe: error: disk `mduuid/00db37a2ad5b8d86c2b04f8cadb67df3' not found.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-96-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-96-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-image-extra-3.19.0-65-generic (3.19.0-65.73~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.19.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-65-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-65-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-65-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/md/2
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-65-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
grub-probe: error: disk `mduuid/00db37a2ad5b8d86c2b04f8cadb67df3' not found.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-65-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-image-3.19.0-65-generic (3.19.0-65.73~14.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-65-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-65-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-65-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
grub-probe: error: disk `mduuid/00db37a2ad5b8d86c2b04f8cadb67df3' not found.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.19.0-65-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.19.0-65-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-image-extra-3.19.0-66-generic (3.19.0-66.74~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.19.0-66-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-66-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-66-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-66-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-66-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/md/2
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-66-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-66-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
grub-probe: error: disk `mduuid/00db37a2ad5b8d86c2b04f8cadb67df3' not found.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-66-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-image-3.19.0-66-generic (3.19.0-66.74~14.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-66-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-66-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-66-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-66-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-66-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
grub-probe: error: disk `mduuid/00db37a2ad5b8d86c2b04f8cadb67df3' not found.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.19.0-66-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.19.0-66-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-image-extra-3.19.0-68-generic (3.19.0-68.76~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.19.0-68-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-68-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-68-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-68-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-68-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/md/2
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-68-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-68-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
grub-probe: error: disk `mduuid/00db37a2ad5b8d86c2b04f8cadb67df3' not found.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-68-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-image-3.19.0-68-generic (3.19.0-68.76~14.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-68-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-68-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-68-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-68-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-68-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
grub-probe: error: disk `mduuid/00db37a2ad5b8d86c2b04f8cadb67df3' not found.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.19.0-68-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.19.0-68-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-image-extra-3.19.0-69-generic (3.19.0-69.77~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.19.0-69-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-69-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-69-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-69-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-69-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/md/2
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-69-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-69-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
grub-probe: error: disk `mduuid/00db37a2ad5b8d86c2b04f8cadb67df3' not found.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-69-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-image-3.19.0-69-generic (3.19.0-69.77~14.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-69-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-69-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-69-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-69-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-69-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
grub-probe: error: disk `mduuid/00db37a2ad5b8d86c2b04f8cadb67df3' not found.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.19.0-69-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.19.0-69-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing libclamav6 (0.98.7+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-3.19.0-65-generic (3.19.0-65.73~14.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-3.19.0-65 (3.19.0-65.73~14.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-3.19.0-66-generic (3.19.0-66.74~14.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-3.19.0-66 (3.19.0-66.74~14.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-3.19.0-68-generic (3.19.0-68.76~14.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-3.19.0-68 (3.19.0-68.76~14.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-3.19.0-69-generic (3.19.0-69.77~14.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-3.19.0-69 (3.19.0-69.77~14.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-91-generic
 linux-image-3.13.0-91-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-92-generic
 linux-image-3.13.0-92-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic
 linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-95-generic
 linux-image-3.13.0-95-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-96-generic
 linux-image-3.13.0-96-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-65-generic
 linux-image-3.19.0-65-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-66-generic
 linux-image-3.19.0-66-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-68-generic
 linux-image-3.19.0-68-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-69-generic
 linux-image-3.19.0-69-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What I have found worth investigating is the id of the drive grub-probe tries to use `` grub-probe: error: disk `mduuid/00db37a2ad5b8d86c2b04f8cadb67df3' not found. `` and cryptsetup printing:`cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/md/2` made me look into fstab, mtab and blkid.

/etc/fstab:

```
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
/dev/md/0 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/md/1 /boot ext3 defaults 0 0
/dev/md/2 / ext4 defaults 0 0
/dev/md/3       /home   ext4    usrquota,grpquota,rw    0       0
```

/etc/mtab:

```
/dev/md2 / ext4 rw 0 0
proc /proc proc rw 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw 0 0
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755 0 0
none /run/lock tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880 0 0
none /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /run/user tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755 0 0
none /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw 0 0
/dev/md1 /boot ext3 rw 0 0
/dev/md3 /home ext4 rw,usrquota,grpquota 0 0
rpc_pipefs /run/rpc_pipefs rpc_pipefs rw 0 0
systemd /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd 0
```

blkid:

```
/dev/sdb1: UUID="fd86d1a9-d020-e196-5d9a-eb7b9a428cc9" UUID_SUB="3d44cfcd-7130-2ea9-f01f-e5468edf00a7" LABEL="rescue:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sdb2: UUID="00db37a2-ad5b-8d86-c2b0-4f8cadb67df3" UUID_SUB="f45b3f70-d70d-24df-d920-0fff84634855" LABEL="rescue:1" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sdb3: UUID="819439a3-93a8-430c-4458-bd01db41509c" UUID_SUB="788658a5-fc00-2743-8b9d-a27cd072a3f9" LABEL="rescue:2" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sdb4: UUID="07345d4c-af16-4aa2-4e2c-eee4f1745ed2" UUID_SUB="4724c84f-b46b-2fc7-ad7c-630251ecbffa" LABEL="rescue:3" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/md0: UUID="b6f91f7d-e7fc-4120-b100-f2a00f7292f1" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/md1: UUID="a6fbed0b-a339-413a-8e1e-c2b1aa7d1d62" TYPE="ext3" 
/dev/md3: UUID="aa7bb374-f63d-4957-8027-a72bf848ae05" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/md2: UUID="cd9a2d40-bc23-47d9-bf68-b62a293fb5b1" TYPE="ext4"
```

I use this machine for website hosting and would like to repair it instead of performing clean install of 16.04. If nothing can be done to repair it then I have no other option but to backup all of data and reinstall it and configure from scratch.

Please help.